# Enable Recovery console from a batch

Tags: windows-server-2003, batch-file

I want to enable the Recovery Console on a lot of Windows 2003 servers.
I want to automate this so I don't have to manually do it on hundreds of servers.

The recovery console install process seems to require human interaction in the form of clicking options in a wizard.

Is there a way of silently installing the recovery console so I can write a script or is this going to be a manual job?

[How to install recovery console](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/378188-install-recovery-console-without-the-windows-xp-cd/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the switches.

```
winnt32.exe /cmdcons /unattend /dudisable
```

I used PSEXEC in a batch files that connects to each host, then I mapped a network drive that contains the i386 folder and ran the silent setup.

here is the batch file

```
net use w: "\\server\I386"` /Persistent:no`
W:
winnt32.exe /cmdcons /unattend /dudisable
```